# ListAdapter is not efficient enough

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I wrote this parent class for all children adapters, which works with view holders to make sure that the app runs smoothly.

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
   // Just a parent class
   GeneralViewHolder holder = null;

    try
    {
        _convertView = convertView;
        _parentView = parent;
        itemPosition = position;

        if (_convertView != null)
      {
          holder = _convertView.Tag as GeneralViewHolder;
      }
      else
      {
          _convertView = createView();
          holder = setupView();
          _convertView.Tag = holder;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GeneralAdapter ex: " + ex.Message);
    }
    populateHolder(holder);
    return _convertView;
}

/// <summary>
/// Inflates the layout.
/// </summary>
protected virtual View createView()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets up the view holder.
/// </summary>
protected virtual GeneralViewHolder setupView()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

/// <summary>
/// Will load data into the viewholder.
/// </summary>
protected virtual GeneralViewHolder populateHolder(GeneralViewHolder _holder)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

As far as I know this should be the view holder model for ListViews.
But somehow this doesn't go smoothly.

Do you know why?

Comment: "doesn't go smoothly" is not a very descriptive explanation of the problem.

Comment: Sorry. I mean it still stutters when scrolling through the list. But I expect a smooth scrolling.

Comment: Well, if it is lagging. Do tell what you have in the view group. Images?

Comment: Yes. One ImageView. The rest is TextViews.

Comment: Where are you tesing this code?

Comment: Please share your list item layout file (XML)

Comment: If your listView is lagging, it's probably due to your http source of your images. You should use a library like Picasso to bind and reuse "smoothly" your images ressources....